# VMware - Can't ping host machine and VM even in bridged mode

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, vmware, bridge

I have set my Ubuntu virtual machine in bridge mode so that my VM could communicate with my host machine but I can't seem to receive any ping replies from both ends. My host machine is windows 10.

Edit: After bridging the VM, it has the same network address as the host machine. Host machine is at 192.168.1.16 while VM is at 192.168.1.25. The ping to 192.168.1.25 says destination unreachable.

Comment: Works fine here pinging from Ubuntu or Kali to a Windows 10 host. Do you have Network Discovery enabled on the Windows 10 host?  Is the Windows 10 machine on a public or private network?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @John this is my home network.

Comment: "Public" or "Private" is a network setting in Windows 10. It does not have anything to do with Home or Office. Other operating systems before Windows 10 have the same setting.  You need to set your network card to Private.

Comment: @John Ah! I just checked, it is a public network.

Comment: You need to set it t Private.  I entered an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Ah! I just checked, it is a public network.

**(A)** You need to check your Network Card setting as to whether it is set to Public or Private.

If set to Public it is more secure and you cannot ping it.

Change it to Private.

**(B)** Also check that Network Discovery (Advanced Network Sharing center) is enabled for Private Networking.

Make sure you can ping this Windows 10 machine from another computer.

If your Windows 10 machine is connected to your router using DHCP (normal), your IP address could have changed.

**(C)** If you wish to try NAT networking, run the VMware Network Editor and reset the NAT network. That is sometimes useful.

After changes, turn off your guest machines, restart Windows 10 and you should be able to Ping. Check to make sure you are pinging the correct IP address.

========

**(D)** You seem to have had something happen to your Windows 10 machine so you might now run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link. Make sure guest machines have been shut down.

Once the repair is complete, try a new guest machine.

Comment: Hi I tried what you said but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I never had any issue pinging a Windows 10 Machine. Did you also check that Network Discovery was enabled?  It may have been disabled when the Network Card was set to Public. I added that to my answer

Comment: Recheck my answer from top to bottom (I added some checkpoints) and try again.

Comment: Okay I have a really odd problem here. Now I don't have another computer but I do have my phone and I'm pinging my guest machine from there and vice versa and everything works fine! it is just the guest and host machine problem I guess.

Comment: Make a new guest machine to test.

Comment: Yep, its not working. Could it be the windows firewall maybe?

Comment: Reset Windows 10 Firewall to defaults.  You may have done something to your Windows 10 machine. I have set VMware guests up many times and never had issues.